# Called python script from another python scrypt keeps the same socket port busy

Tags: python, tcp, subprocess, port

My goal is to have a socket server running that accepts commands from a client. This server will be used to show processes status, kill and start python scripts.
Now the server is working fine and listens on port 48410.
Whenever in the server script I start another python script (using `suprocess.call`), the called script runs but the server stops working on the port 48410.
The client script has a socket but uses a different port. If I use fuser to check who's keeping the 48410 port busy I see both my main server and the called python script.
This is how I call the script:

```
subprocess.call(['python /home/pi/zpp/loggy7/loggy7.py'], shell=True)
```

And this is what I get with `ps -ax |grep logg` after the call:

```
13084 ?        S      0:00 /bin/sh -c python /home/pi/zpp/loggy7/loggy7.py
13086 ?        S      0:00 python /home/pi/zpp/loggy7/loggy7.py
```

I use `fuser` to see who is using that port:

```
pi@raspy:~ $ fuser -vi 48410/tcp
48410/tcp:           pi        13048 F.... python
                     pi        13084 F.... sh
                     pi        13086 F.... python
```

Whatever I tried to run the second python script, even if it is a simply one that not uses sockets, it gets the same port busy. The result is that if I quit the main script I can't run it again before having stopped the called script.

Comment: (I guess the problem isn't starting a (python) child, but that child doing funky things with inherited descriptors on exit, if not startup: you may need to close descriptors between fork&exec.)

Comment: Consider [answering your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).